# Joomla blank template loading very slowly

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I made a site in Joomla! and its loading very slowly.

For testing purpose I removed all the contents from my templates and rendered a blank template without any modules, comp,css, images etc.

enabled debug and tested but it loading something 6.8 MB

the debug result

Profile Information

```
Application 0.000 seconds (+0.000); 0.77 MB (+0.767) - afterLoad
Application 1.077 seconds (+1.077); 3.83 MB (+3.065) - afterInitialise
Application 1.092 seconds (+0.015); 4.50 MB (+0.673) - afterRoute
Application 1.163 seconds (+0.071); 6.79 MB (+2.283) - afterDispatch
Application 1.167 seconds (+0.004); 6.82 MB (+0.034) - afterRender
```

Hosted in ISS server.

Please help.

Comment: what data do you have? It's not usually the template that determnes the speed o a site since that is almost all cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have cache enabled? do you have 3rd party plugins? did you try disabling some system plugins? did you try on apache web server? (it also runs on windows)